# CSS Web page not responsive when using vh and vw

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have following, simple web page. Here I have used vh for image height. But when I resize it to small screen sizes, the size of the background section doesn't resize properly.

Are there any solutions for this problem without remvoing vh.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>

   section{
       background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
       padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;
   }

   .edit_image img{
       max-height: 80vh;
       padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    }

   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-full" style="padding: 20px;"> 
        <section>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12  text-center">
                <div class='edit_image' img_id=0><img src='http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-4.jpg'></div>           
              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Wrong (Small screen):**

[image: Wrong]

**Correct (Normal Web page):**

[image: Correct]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution for you.  Basically just added `max-width` to the css. Also created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9p619qwq/

Please note that the fixed padding (for both the `<section>` and `<img>`) is going to cause issues when the page gets smaller as the width and the padding ratios are going to overlap.

```css
section{
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
  padding: 10px 0px 30px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.edit_image img{
  max-height: 80vh;
  max-width: 80vw;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-full" style="padding: 20px;"> 
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12  text-center">
        <div class='edit_image' img_id=0>
          <img src='http://cdn.wonderfulengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Desktop-Wallpaper-4.jpg'>
        </div>           
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

hey i notice you forgot to add the viewport meta:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` perhaps this will solve your problem